# Palindrome in repeated loop

Tags: c++, loops, palindrome

Checking 5 entries whether they're palindrome or not, the code i've written gives the correct output for the first entry but not the remaining ones. I've dry run the code yet couldn't find where the fault is.

Here's the code:

```
while (count < 5)
    {
        cin >> n;
        store = n;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10 + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        if (store == reverse)
            cout << "it's a palindrome " << endl;
        else
            cout << "Not a palindrome " << endl;

        count++;
    }
```

All variables are of int data type

Comment: You are not re initializing ```reverse```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare `reverse` inside first while loop because if you don't `reverse` will still hold the value from previous iteration and produce wrong result. As shown below:

```
while (count < 5)
{
    cin >> n;
    store = n;
    int reverse=0; // <--- declare here;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10 + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    if (store == reverse)
        cout << "it's a palindrome " << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not a palindrome " << endl;

    count++;
}
```

Comment: Same for `store` and `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not resetting `reverse` between the runs. Add `reverse = 0;` at the beginning of your loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int count = 0, store = 0, n = 0;
    int reverse = 0;
    while (count < 5)
    {
        reverse = 0;
        std::cin >> n;
        store = n;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10 + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        if (store == reverse)
            std::cout << "it's a palindrome " << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Not a palindrome " << std::endl;

        count++;
    }
}
```